# Is it possible to validate if the file inside the compressed file is .EXE or a broken file when uploading in PHP?

Tags: php, validation, upload, compression

Is it possible to validate if the compressed file that was trying to upload by a user has a file extension of .EXE?

Something like this. (Note: This is just an example so I don't have the actual code.

1st step

- Validate if the file uploaded by a user is compressed (ex. .rar / .zip) or image (ex. .jpg / .png)

2nd step

- If image then it is ok.
- If it is a compressed file then check if it is corrupt or if the file inside the compressed file ends in image extension (.jpg / .png).

3rd step

- Output the result whether the file that was trying to be uploaded by the user is corrupt / an application (.exe) or a success (an image, ex. .jpg or .png).

Comment: Yes, use [zip](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) or [rar](http://php.net/manual/en/book.rar.php) functions to list what's in the archive and extract files.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that one! I'll conduct an experiment.

Also, to the down-voter, please explain why would you down-vote me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like what georg said, I can simply use [zip](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) or [rar](http://php.net/manual/en/book.rar.php) function to list what's in the archive and extract the files in it.